# how to set space between buttons in vbox layout in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a screen which I think the vbox should be the right layout to use.
What I want is a screeen which has 3 or 4 buttons on it and they are evenly spread on the screen.
The buttons should have space around them and be centered.

Here is my code :

```
{
                title: 'Main Menu',
                iconCls: 'organize',
                layout: 'vbox',
                scrollbale: true,
                items: [{
                            xtype: 'titlebar',
                            title: 'Main Menu',
                            docked:'top'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Button 1',
                            //cls: 'menu_button',
                            flex: 1,
                            ui: 'round',
                            //align: 'center',
                            style: 'margin: 10px; width: 85%; height:30px !important;',
                            //pack:'center',
                            handler: function () {
                                // navigate to the Quote page
                                                }
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'About',
                            xtype: 'button',
                            ui: 'round',
                            centered: true,
                            //cls: 'menu_button',
                            style: 'margin: 10px; width: 85%; height:30px;',
                            flex: 1,
                            handler: function () { }
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'FAQ',
                            xtype: 'button',
                            //cls: 'menu_button',
                            style: 'margin: 10px; width: 85%; height:30px !important;',
                            flex: 1,
                            ui: 'round',
                            handler: function () { }
                        }]

            }
```

To make my problem clear, here is the screenshot
[image]

So as you can see, the buttons are not evenly big even I have set their width and height and they do not have spaces between them.

The layout I want is something like this:

[image]

Please point me to the right direction.

Thank you my friends.

Comment: hello? can anyone please say something? Do I ask the wrong question? Why doesn't it get even one reply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/woosah/3zdc7/5/

```
config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        scrollable: true,
        layout: 'vbox',
        defaults: {
            flex: 1
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Main Menu',
            docked: 'top'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Button 1',
            ui: 'round',
            margin: '40px 40px 0 40px'
        }, {
            text: 'About',
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'round',
            margin: '40px 40px 0 40px'
        }, {
            text: 'FAQ',
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'round',
            margin: '40px'
        }]
}
```

Comment: excellent. But could you please explain why yours works, mine doesn't? That's more important to me

Comment: Youre main problem was the "centered: true," on the middle button.
if u remove it. and add a "auto" in youre "margin" like this: 
"margin: 10px auto; to center it. ;)